# Why does config.Appsettings.Settings["MySetting"].Value fail in Windows 7, but not other versions

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I'm reading a setting out of the app.config file using code nearly identical to that which I've used in other portions of the app. It works fine under WinXP and Win Server 2003, when I run it under Windows 7 64-bit it generates an exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
string exePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, applicationName);

// Get the configuration file. The file name has this format appname.exe.config.

System.Configuration.Configuration utilConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);
string fileName = utilConfig.AppSettings.Settings["MsgAlertWav"].Value; //<<Fails here
```

This is simplified code, but generates the error under Windows 7. It's a .NET 3.0 project compiled for 32-bit target. I have this same code in another module and it works fine under Windows 7.

I am mystified since this code works in one module, but not another and generates no build errors.

Comment: This is most likely problem with rights. Users don't have the right to write to Program Files. You would need to get elevated to do that (and it's probably not a good idea here). Isn't setting user-specific setting good enough for you?

Comment: Well, I'm actually trying to read from the app.config. The Users group does have Read rights to the folder. I don't think it's a rights issue in this case. It's working fine in another module reading a different app.config in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MsgAlertWav"];
```

or have a look at the

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings **is deprecated** and is meant for solutions on framework versions 1.0 and 1.1.

Since you are using a 3.0 you should be using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager. Is pretty mcuh the same thing, has the same usage

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager["MsgAlertWav"];
```

hth, -covo