# Modifying App.config in Program Files directory

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

Kind of a two part issue.

I developed an app which reads from and writes to an App.config. 
The application is installed in Program Files by my MSI installer.

It works fine on my Win7 computer but I have users on Win7 that get Access Denied when writing to this App.config.

I am writing to the app.config using the below code:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["Endpoint"].Value = endpointTxtBox.Text;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

1. Why don't I get this issue on my development pc? I have tried both with a local admin and normal local user account.
2. How do I relocate the App.config to an unprotected directory?

Comment: check this explanation --> http://superuser.com/questions/321502/why-does-chrome-install-itself-under-user-directory-instead-of-program-files

Comment: I am sure this is because you're admin on your machine but users are not admins on theirs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654780/why-does-config-appsettings-settingsmysetting-value-fail-in-windows-7-but-n

Comment: Would this `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("Endpoint", endpointTxtBox.Text)` do the same thing for you? And an Idea. When users run your application, try to right click and do "Run As Administrator" - it may work

Comment: @T.S. I've tried it with non admin users and they dont get errors either.

Comment: If `Run As Administrator` is not helping, go to your app folder and add permissions manually to that folder, and see how that works

Comment: Run as Administrator will work but its not an option as the user shouldnt need administrator privleges. Im really looking for a way to relocate the app.config to an unprotected directory.

Comment: @CathalMF: Did you find a way to relocate app.config to an unprotected directory. Please share your solution around it

Comment: @prasy No. I ended up writing a custom config file utility.

Comment: @CathalMF: Can you please give any reference or link how you did so, that i can follow it and learn

Comment: @prasy I dont have any links but if you google how to Serialize and Deserialize a class to XML. Basically you create a class which will contain all your settings. You can then convert this class to XML and save it to a file or read the XML file and convert it to a class.

Answer (score 2):

Cathal,
  You should not have to move the app.config in order to let your users save their application settings; .NET already has support for saving user-scoped app settings in user-writable storage baked in!  You can even specify the *default* user settings in the app.config file.

Check this link for details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1(v=vs.110).aspx

Note that making use of a strongly-typed .NET Settings class rather than the raw, more weakly-typed AppSettings NameValueCollection.  (The settings can still stored in the app.config, though.)

You can create a Settings file in VS (the template is called "Settings file" in VS).

A couple of things confused me about Settings files at first, so I thought I would point them out to you:

1) First: the .settings file. The VS designer lets you define your app settings, their types, and their scopes (i.e. user or application).  **This is the file the designer modifies when you user the designer, but runtime configuration changes will never be written to this file.  It defines your app settings and their default values.  That's it.**  I didn't get that at first when I was trying to wrap my head around Settings files.

Also, notice that the build action on the .settings file is set to SettingsSingleFileGenerator.

2) The .designer.cs file.  VS/MSBuild generates this file at build-time for you because the build action on the .settings file is set to SettingsSingleFileGenerator.  The class that it generates is a strongly typed wrapper for your configuration properties, and you can use it equally well for your application-scoped and user-scoped properties.

3)  The runtime settings that your Settings class wraps are still stored in the app.config.

4)  User settings are stored underneath that user's AppData\Local directory so that they have full read/write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple of other ideas, if what you need to do really is let the user modify the global application settings for all users.

1. Externalize some of your configuration by using the configSource attribute. You store the entire
   appSettings section, for instance, in a separate file by doing this:

   `<appSettings configSource="....\file.config" />`

   Here are the docs for that feature: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154(v=vs.85).aspx
2. I believe you can manually load a config file anywhere you want using the System.Configuration.ConfigXmlDocument class.  Construct one using the no-arg constructor and then call its `Load(String filename)` method.
3. Store your configuration in the registry rather than the filesystem by implementing a custom [SettingsProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsprovider(v=vs.110).aspx).